# Gitlab custom domain, failed to verify domain ownership

Tags: dns, gitlab, namecheap, gitlab-pages

I don't think I need to use the subdomain. I have created a A record and a TXT record as the doc suggests on namecheap.com. After wait for 24 hours, I sill get a `failed to verify domain ownership` error.

[image: namechap DNS config]

[image: gitlab pages custom domain]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove your `CNAME` record. Also, remove the URL redirection and your first `TXT` record. You shouldn't be using both `CNAME` and `A` records together.

> If using a DNS A record, you can place the TXT record directly under the domain. If using a DNS CNAME record, the two record types won't co-exist, so you need to place the TXT record in a special subdomain of its own. [[source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.html#dns-txt-record)]

So your final configuration would be:

```
A Record        @   35.185.44.232
TXT Record      @   gitlab-pages-verification-code=XXXXXX
```

Comment: Done. Thanks for you reply. I guess I still need to wait for at least 24 hours for it work.

Comment: I am still getting `Failed to verify domain ownership` error.

Comment: @yongho `cointoss.club` is your actual domain, correct? I did a ping to your domain and didn't get a reply. It doesn't look like your `A` record and `TXT` record was set according to [this](http://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=cointoss.club). Please check.

Comment: Yes it is my domain. I just noticed the A record should be like:
`A @ 52.167.214.135`

Comment: @yongho Oh. Yeah, with some dns managers `@` is used. I can see your `A` record now and it points to GitLab. But I still can't see your `TXT` record. Have you managed to verify yet? If not, change the `TXT` record to `@` as well.

Comment: This worked! Gitlab's docs makes this way too complex. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, I fixed it with this as well.  Gitlab's documents are not just complex, they're downright wrong.  The settings page kept telling me to add CNAME and TXT while I actually needed A and TXT records.  It also told me to add some keys (`example.com` and `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.example.com`) instead of `@`.  It's hard to tell if I'm messing up or not if DNS can supposedly take up to 24 hours to update.  Small note: IP of gitlab changed to `35.185.44.232` since somewhere August 2018, for anyone else wondering.